# Did Sakuya end up being healed?

Tags: utawarerumono

When Genjimaru escapes with Sakuya and intends to give her to Hakuro (as a hostage in exchange for Hakuro's trust and help stopping Kuuya), it's revealed that before the escape Genjimaru had cut the tendons on Sakuya's legs so she couldn't walk, thus being unable to escape Hakuro and being the perfect hostage for him.

The final scene shows Sakuya and the still regressed Kuuya outside. However, no scene has shown Sakuya having walked at all after she is left with Hakuro. This final scene and the scenes with only Sakuya and Kuuya show only the two of them and no third person who could have carried Sakuya.

So I am wondering if Sakuya ended up being healed at some point, or if Kuuya was carrying her all this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that Kuuya or some random NPC helped her to get outside. However, since there is literally no additional information given about Kuuya or Sakuya after the events of Utawarerumono (or the amount of time that passes by after the final battle), it is quite difficult to say. I would say that she hasn't healed because of a few reasons:

1. Her field sprite depicts her sitting down. Though she may be merely looking over Kuuya as she plays in the field, I think Sakuya would have been right next to her if she was able to walk. I think the sprite designers would have made her standing if she was healed.
2. Tendon injuries take a long time to heal. Genjimaru outright cut them and given the limited amount of medical research and prowess that is shown in the Utawarerumono universe, I doubt that it would be enough to have her healed any time soon. The time factor I mentioned earlier also comes into play, because it isn't directly stated how much time has passed.
3. I need to bring up the anime for this one, even though they decided not to mention her tendons being cut at all. In every scene after Genjimaru and Sakuya joined Hakuoro, she is sitting. Every scene after that shows her sitting and she is never seen walking or standing again. Even in the ending scene, Sakuya remains seated.

Sadly, I doubt she would be able to walk again...